# When I mouse over an image, I want it to keep enlarging until I don't have my mouse on it anymore

Tags: javascript, html

I know this code is wrong (the while loop specifically). I am wondering how to keep enlarging the image (id = "image") **while** I have my mouse over it. I have it now so that when I mouse over the image, it enlarges once. When I stop having my mouse on it, it goes back to its original size. Any help?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img onmouseover="enlarge()" onmouseout="decrease()" height="100" width="100" src="http://www.mariowiki.com/images/thumb/5/57/Powerup-mini-mushroom-sm.png/200px-Powerup-mini-mushroom-sm.png" id="image">
        <script>

            function enlarge() {
                var image = document.getElementById('image');
                if(image && image.style) {
                    while(onmouseover = document.getElementById('image')){
                        image.style.height = '200px';
                        image.style.width = '200px';    
                    }
                }
            }

            function decrease(){
                var image = document.getElementById('image');
                if(image && image.style) {
                    image.style.height = '100px';
                    image.style.width = '100px';
                } 
            }


        </script>
    </body>
</html
```

Comment: What is this? `onmouseover = document.getElementById('image')`

Comment: That is the part that is wrong. I was wondering how to make it work.

Comment: you want to make a animation? ( kinda enlarging animation )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` instead of `while` to execute some actions by some interval. The second argument stands for the *approximate* time interval in ms - in my example it is 13 - 0.013 seconds.
Then, you can use `clearInterval` to stop executing it.

```js
var increaseInterval;

function enlargeStep() // one step of enlarging
{
    document.getElementById('image').width += 1;
    document.getElementById('image').height += 1;
}

function enlarge()
{
  increaseInterval = setInterval(enlargeStep, 13); // start doing steps every 13ms
  enlargeStep(); // do it right now, so that effect is seen immediately
}

function decrease()
{
  clearInterval(increaseInterval); // stop executing these steps
  document.getElementById('image').height = 100; // reset values
  document.getElementById('image').width = 100;
}
```

```html
<img onmouseover="enlarge()" onmouseout="decrease()" height="100" width="100" src="http://www.mariowiki.com/images/thumb/5/57/Powerup-mini-mushroom-sm.png/200px-Powerup-mini-mushroom-sm.png" id="image">
```

However, if you want to make smooth animations, then you may be interested in the `.animate()` method of jQuery library:

```js
function enlarge()
{
  $("#image").animate({
      'height': '300px',
      'width': '300px'
  });
}

function decrease()
{
  $("#image").animate({
      'height': '100px',
      'width': '100px'
  });
}
```

```css
#image {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img onmouseover="enlarge()" onmouseout="decrease()" src="http://www.mariowiki.com/images/thumb/5/57/Powerup-mini-mushroom-sm.png/200px-Powerup-mini-mushroom-sm.png" id="image">
```

Comment: How do I make it so that after I move my mouse off of the image, I can move the mouse back onto the image and have it enlarge again?

Comment: Cool! I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Wyredain That's how it works. Try it. When you move it over - it starts enlarging, when you move it out - it resets :)